`IMjournal.sty' not found
I'm submitting an article to a journal where it asks me to follow their latex template and upload an IMjournal.sty file. I don't know how to include it in the tex file and compile it without getting this message error :"`IMjournal.sty' not found."

Welcome to TeX.SE, please refer https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-03 before you start work in LaTeX

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ask your journal for the .sty file.
